# Hide a div if parent span is empty javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have limited experience with javascript and am trying to add a style to a div using a script.

I have an instance on a cms that I cannot access the code directly, All I can alter is the `<div class="overlay">` and the javascript. I need to be able to hide a div if the span containing the div is empty.

The Html:

```
<div class="textrow div_SA" style="height:16px;">
    <span class="spn_SA" style="font-weight:bold;color:#B22222;">
        <div class="overlay"></div> Save $10.00
    </span>
</div>
```

The javascript I am trying to use (found here and modified a bit)

```
window.onload = function () {
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var i = 0,
        L = spans.length,
        tem, pa;
    while (i < L) {
        tem = spans[i++];
        if ((tem.className.indexOf('spn_SA') != -1) && ((tem.textContent === 0 || tem.textContent === null) && !tem.innerText)) {
            tem.childNode.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
};
```

The outcome would be that if the span did not contain the text `Save $10.00` the script would add `display:none` to the `<div class="overlay"></div>` (I am using this div to display a sale sign image)

Comment: DIV can not be a child of SPAN - you are creating invalid HTML, so don't expect things to work as you expect.

Comment: The span *containing the div* is never empty :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://jquery.com/ and do this

Assign a id to the element, say

And check for condition

> $("#myspan").text() === ""

Comment: or `document.geteElementById('myspan').innerText.length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ((tem.textContent === 0 || tem.textContent === null) && !tem.innerText)
> ```

This will never be `true`. The [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) is always a string (or - if not supported - `undefined`). Use

```
/\S/.test(tem.textContent || tem.innerText || "")
```

which tests for the existence of any non-whitespace character.

> ```
> tem.childNode.style.display = "none";
> ```

What do you expect `childNode` to be? You probably want to use [`.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.firstElementChild) or [`.children[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.children).

Comment: Thank you, I am now using: `window.onload = function () {
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var i = 0,
        L = spans.length,
        tem, pa;
    while (i < L) {
        tem = spans[i++];
        if ((tem.className.indexOf('spn_SA') != -1) && (tem.textContent || tem.innerText || "")) {
            tem.firstChildElement.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
};` however still no luck

Comment: @user2422081: `firstElementChild` not `firstChildElement`. The errormessage you're getting should indicate that.